# Maven error when running the testcases

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, junit, build

I have a Jenkins environment where I am trying to build a java project. Locally, this java project builds without any errors. But in the Jenkins environment it has the same error in each testcase:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.junit.runner.Runner
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:61)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:26)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:262)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:124)
```

I can not find out why this happens or how to debug to solve the error.
Any proposals?

Comment: Is it a free style jenkins job or a maven jenkins job? which command are you using during the concerned job step? can you execute an `mvn help:effective-pom` and `mvn help:effective-settings` as part of the same jenkins job and check the output to spot whether anything weird comes up?

Comment: Thanks for your help. it is a maven jenkins job. The command i am using is mvn clean install  and the commands you gave me, give me the same output

Comment: The commands I proposed should have changed the output (that is, the error would still be there) but rather provide further details for troubleshooting